# Function of Helper in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, function

I have:

```
 function fetchlinks(){
    ## include the simpledom helper #########################################################
    $this->load->helper('simpledom');
    $this->simpledom->file_get_html("http://www.thesite.net/thesitepath");
        ############################################################################################  
        $htmlToSearch = file_get_html("http://www.thesite.net/thesitepath");
        foreach($htmlToSearch->find('a') as $element){
            echo "<h1 style='color:red; '>".$element->href."</h1> <br />";
        }    
    }
```

I'm calling and using the function here:

```
$this->load->helper('simpledom');
$this->simpledom->file_get_html("http://www.thesite.net/thesitepath");
```

How do I then use the contents of the ^^ *above line* in my `foreach{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helper functions are just declared functions that get loaded if they are needed. They are not properties of the CI Instance.

Refer to the [documentation here.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html)

Comment: I understand that, but how do I use this "$this->simpledom->file_get_html("http://www.thesite.net/thesitepath");" now from here in my foreach{} block ?